# validate params then navigate with React Router v6

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I want to validate the params in my component and do a redirect if they don't pass some logic.

Two things can go wrong:

1. React gives me a rendering warning:

```
Warning: Cannot update a component (`BrowserRouter`) while rendering a different component (`Home`).
```

2. When refreshing the page directly with the bad param I get the warning:

```
You should call navigate() in a React.useEffect(), not when your component is first rendered.
```

I'm not sure I understand why I can't `return null`, or return any random element from the logic and still have it redirect properly.

I understand it works with `useEffect`, but I actually want to end execution of the rendering of my component early, to prevent logic further down in the component from running, in the case that the params aren't properly formatted.

See the codesandbox here, (you have to change the url to add an id number): https://codesandbox.io/s/nostalgic-cloud-di0ovf

```js
import "./styles.css";
import {
  BrowserRouter,
  Routes,
  Route,
  Link,
  useNavigate,
  useParams,
} from "react-router-dom";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/:id" element={<Home />} />
        <Route path="/users" element={<Users />} />
      </Routes>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
}

function Users() {
  return (
    <div>
      <nav>
        <Link to="/1">Go To 1 (bad param)</Link>
      </nav>
      <h2>Users</h2>
    </div>
  );
}

function Home() {
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  const {id} = useParams();
  
  // check for properly formed params
  if( id < 3){
    navigate({pathname:'/users', replace:true})
    return <span>nothing</span>;
  }

  // other logic that depends on properly formed params
  // don't run this with mal-formed params!

  return (
    <div>
      <nav>
        <Link to="/1">Go To 1 (bad param)</Link>
      </nav>
      <h1>Home: {id}</h1>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: `navigate` in `useEffect` and then return early below effect as `if(id < 3) return null`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should split the logic of issuing the intentional side-effect of navigating from the logic of rendering valid JSX.

Example:

```
function Home() {
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const { id } = useParams();

  useEffect(() => {
    if (id < 3) {
      navigate('/users', { replace: true });
    }
  }, [id, navigate]);
  
  // check for properly formed params
  if (id < 3) {
    return <span>nothing</span>; // or null
  }

  // other logic that depends on properly formed params
  // don't run this with mal-formed params!

  return (
    <div>
      <nav>
        <Link to="/1">Go To 1 (bad param)</Link>
      </nav>
      <h1>Home: {id}</h1>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Alternatively you can render a declarative redirect instead.

Example:

```
function Home() {
  const { id } = useParams();

  // check for properly formed params
  if (id < 3) {
    return <Navigate to='/users' replace />;
  }

  // other logic that depends on properly formed params
  // don't run this with mal-formed params!

  return (
    <div>
      <nav>
        <Link to="/1">Go To 1 (bad param)</Link>
      </nav>
      <h1>Home: {id}</h1>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Hey Drew, `You should call navigate() in a React.useEffect(), not when your component is first rendered.` what is the meaning of this warning and how does it effect` ?

Comment: @KcH `navigate` shouldn't be called as an unintentional side-effect directly from the function body, it should be called from a "lifecycle method", a.k.a. `useEffect` hook. Keep in mind that the *entire* function body of a React function component is effectively the "render method" and should treated as a pure function.

Comment: Thanks Drew  ... makes sense to me now 